# How to register Zendesk application (SAML based) in Azure AD B2C Tenant to perform SSO?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, zendesk, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have followed the Zendesk documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/zendesk-tutorial) for creating an enterprise application in Azure AD (B2B) and successfully performed SSO via SAML.

Now, I want to use the same application to be registered in Azure AD B2C Tenant for performing SSO. But, not successful as the login is not succeeding. Am trying the JWT Token approach (https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203663816-Enabling-JWT-JSON-Web-Token-single-sign-on) for AAD B2C. Request you to help me how to configure an app to perform SSO via SAML (just like in AAD B2B Enterprise Apps) in Azure AD B2C Tenant.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the answer provided was helpful for you ? if so could you please accept the answer (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in) as solution for your ask. This could be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying the JWT approach?

Is that how you did it in Azure AD? I assume the enterprise application used SAML?

Why can't you use SAML in B2C? as in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

Answer (score 0):

There are built-in policies for sign-in and sign-up but for  SAML, new Custom Policy is required to be created.

**Steps to create a Custom  Policy to support SAML SSO.**

- 1.Create Policy Keys and Identity Experience Framework Application.
- 2.Create Certificate
- 3.Download Sample Policies
- 4.Update Base file
- 5.Update Base_Extension File
- 6.Create policy file.
- 7.Upload Policy in Azure Portal
- 8.Run Policy.

you can refer following links

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy   **to Register a SAML application in Azure AD B2C**
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider-options?pivots=b2c-custom-policy  **to explore the Options for registering a SAML application in Azure AD**
  B2C
- SAML test application for testing: https://aka.ms/samltestapp

---

Few Other links to refer

- The detailed steps for the SAML-Based SSO With Azure AD B2C as an IDP
  can be refered from the following  link
  https://dzone.com/articles/saml-based-sso-with-azure-ad-b2c-as-an-idp
- The following link
  https://plugins.miniorange.com/saml-single-sign-on-sso-wordpress-using-azure-b2c
  provides a step-by-step video  to Setup SSO between WordPress
  application and Azure B2C   which can be helpfull too.